# How to add a row to a table using VBA in Excel, where the 1st column has an incrementing index

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting up a table in excel that has to be filled dynamically using macros. The table consists of 2 columns, where the first one has to be an index column and the second one is a value column. As you can see in my code, the 2nd column works fine. However, I don't know how to 'pre-fill' the first column such that the result will be an index column.

See the image below for what I mean concretely.

[image: table]

I am looking for an auto-incrementing function that returns the incremented value, every time a row is added. Or just a simple hack that works too :)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Table")

    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub 'possible way of handing no worksheet was set
    End If

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("FAB_data")

    Dim newrow As ListRow
    Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add

    With newrow
        .Range(1) = 'index_function_goes_here'
        .Range(2) = wb.Sheets("Oct").Range("AG6")
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
.Range(1) = .Range.Row - .Parent.HeaderRowRange.Row - 1
```

or

```
.Range(1) = .Range(1).Offset(-1).Value + 1
```

Comment: I think the 2nd part of this answer is better than the accepted, it sets the cell to an actual number rather than a formula.

Comment: @PieterT2000: What should happen if you insert a row into the table?